# Laplace Transformation to Solve $f(t)=t^2+\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)f(s) \ ds$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, laplace-transform

> I am trying to solve the Volterra integral equation $$f(t)=t^2-\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)f(s) \ ds,$$ using the Laplace transformation.

I first rewrite the equation as $$f(t)=t^2-(f*t)(t),$$ where $*$ denotes the convolution of $f$ and $t$. Taking the Laplace transform of each term (Laplace transform is linear),
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}(f)(z)&=\mathcal{L}(t^2)(z)-\mathcal{L}(f*t)(z) \\
\mathcal{L}(f)(z)&=\frac{2}{z^3}-\frac{\mathcal{L}(f)(z)}{z^2} \\
\implies \mathcal{L}(f)(z)&=\frac{2}{z(1+z^2)}. \\
\end{align}
Using the inversion formula $$f(t)=\sum_{j=1}^{3}\text{Res}(\mathcal{L}(f)(z)e^{zt},z=a_j),$$
we conclude that $$f(t)=2-(e^{it}+e^{-it})=2-2\cos(t).$$

Is this solution correct? I have minimal experience using the Laplace transform and would like to know of any errors in my logic before I attempt more complicated questions.

Comment: if you got something very simple, then why not back substitute and check your own answer?

Comment: I don't know why I didn't do that. Yep, it seems legit

Comment: nice solved :).+1